# Android - Real time location sharing

Tags: java, android, mysql, google-maps-android-api-2, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop a app, through which we can share our real time location with another users who are using same app. I have designed the GUI in which I have showed the friend list and share button in front of each friend. When we click on share button then our location will be shared with that friend's device. Does this project need database or is there any Google service to do this more easily? I just need a guidance about this project.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

double x,y;
Timer timer;
    LocationManager lm;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {  Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "nothing is enabled", duration);
            toast.show();
}
if (gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerNetwork);
         timer=new Timer();
         timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
}
LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            x =location.getLatitude();
            y = location.getLongitude();
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps enabled "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            x = location.getLatitude();
            y = location.getLongitude();
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network enabled"+x + "\n" + y, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
   {x = gps_loc.getLatitude();
                y = gps_loc.getLongitude();
                  Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                 else
   {x = net_loc.getLatitude();
                y = net_loc.getLongitude();
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                toast.show();
}
}
if(gps_loc!=null){
     {x = gps_loc.getLatitude();
                y = gps_loc.getLongitude();
                  Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();
                  }
}
             if(net_loc!=null){
   {x = net_loc.getLatitude();
                y = net_loc.getLongitude();
              Context context = getApplicationContext();
              int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                toast.show();
}
             }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "no last know avilable", duration);
            toast.show();
}
}}
```